docker build not installing vite
I'm trying to build a dockerfile for a project that I pulled from elsewhere.
Here is the dockerfile:
FROM node:22 AS build

ENV NODE_ENV=production 


WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --verbose
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build


FROM node:20-slim

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .


ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 4173
CMD ["npm","run", "preview","--", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]

Running docker build with this outputs an error when it gets to RUN npm run build due to vite not being found.
I checked in my package.json and have confirmed that vite is present in the dependencies as shown below.
package.json:
{
    "name": "svelte-latest",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^3.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^4.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
        "eslint": "^9.15.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.46.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.49",
        "svelte": "^5.0.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.4.15",
        "vite": "^5.0.3"
    },
    "overrides": {
        "vite": {
            "rollup": "npm:@rollup/wasm-node"
        }
    },
    "optionalDependencies": {
        "@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-musl": "4.6.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "pg": "^8.13.1",
        "postgres": "^3.4.5"
    }
}

Looking at the logs that came from RUN npm install --verbose, The only things that seemed to be installed were related to pg and postgres.
In an attempt to fix this, I amended my dockerfile to add RUN npm install -g vite --verbose to the line before RUN npm install --verbose
This caused another problem where running docker build hangs indefinitely on RUN npm install -g vite --verbose for hours as shown here:
 => [frontend build 5/8] RUN npm install -g vite --verbose                                                                                              1296.5s 
 => => # npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@rollup%2frollup-linux-x64-gnu 88ms (cache miss)                                                     
 => => # npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@rollup%2frollup-linux-x64-musl 115ms (cache miss)                                                   
 => => # npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2fwin32-ia32 286ms (cache miss)
 => => # npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@rollup%2frollup-freebsd-x64 339ms (cache miss)
 => => # npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@rollup%2frollup-linux-riscv64-gnu 368ms (cache miss)
 => => # npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@rollup%2frollup-linux-arm-gnueabihf 384ms (cache miss)  

How can I remedy this? I have no problem running npm install locally and this only happens on docker.

Because you set NODE_ENV=production, the devDependencies aren't getting installed.

Ok that worked. I set the NODE_ENV to development. But now I'm confused on why the npm install still froze when I moved all the devDependencies into the Dependencies before this.

i dont see if there is any point with changing your node version after build and npm installing its not ideal at all.
i recommend you to choose one version and stay with it.
thats the version i recommend:
FROM node:20-eslim

ENV NODE_ENV=production 


WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --verbose
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 4173
CMD ["npm","run", "preview","--", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]


regarding docekr freezing and hanging when building the docker image, its mostly because the permission issue.
have you tried to run the docker with sudo? (if you are on linux)
sudo docker build -t myviteapp:latest .

